# AWS CloudWatch logs open from middle

Tags: amazon-web-services

All of sudden the AWS CloudWatch logs started to open from the middle, or from the beginning of the log stream. They used to open from the end of the log stream showing the latest lines. I wonder if this is something that I can configure or has AWS just changed something.

It is really frustrating when you want to follow how the progresses of your lambda app but cannot do it because when you open the log in AWS it shows the first lines in that log stream, and in order to see the latest lines you need to set a custom time frame. And it doesn't allow you to set a future timestamp into the end time, which forces you to always update the end time to see the new lines. I hope there is a solution for getting it to open the trail of the log stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking on ALL in timeframe option? For me recently they started setting start time, and logs are visible from that time onwards, like you described, but when I click on ALL, it shows logs regularly, like it used to.

Second thing you can do is to have rolling start of logs (like, last 15 minutes, 1 hour).

To do that, add:

`;start=PT1H` at the end of your URL if you want last hour
`;start=PT15M` at the end of your URL if you want last 15 minutes
You can change numbers depending on timeframe you want